# How to Check if objectA has all message as objectB in smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak, gnu-smalltalk

I am using smalltalk - i need to check if `objectA` has all the messages(methods) that `objectB` has .

i need to write my own code, how could it be done ?

Comment: Please, ask for something more specific and, most of all, show here what you have done to find this problem. Otherwise, it just seems that you are repeating here something that was asked to you in the context of a course. The question alone, without more context, seems artificial.

Comment: what isnt clear in my question ?

Comment: @Francy The question makes sense. But you could for example explain if your problem is, how to find out all the messages one object understands, or if you have trouble comparing the results.

Comment: @Francy Also try to get the terminology right. An _object_ might _understand a message_ based on the _methods it's class and it's superclasses implement_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could for example ask the class of an object which selectors it's instances understand:

```
objectA class allSelectors
```

Then you could ask different objects and compare the results.

Answer (score 2):

The solution might be

```
objectA class allSelectors includesAll: objectB class allSelectors
```

Comment: Note that using just #selectors is not enough, because you miss the methods defined in superclass/es. You should use #allSelectors, like @MartinW said

Comment: True. I thought that the question is not clear about that and was focused on classes where the question is ambiguous. But on an object base I think you are right